# post operation async plugin is not firing on CRM on Premise

Tags: c#, dynamics-crm

I have registered my plugin as a post async plugin that runs in “None” isolation mode. It runs when I am in debug mode but not from the web when I create a record on the target entity "annotation".

I would like to add that the assembly is registered to store in database.

Code:

```
public void Execute(IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
{
    try
    {
        if (context.InputParameters.Contains("Target") && context.InputParameters["Target"] is Entity)
        {
            // Obtain the target entity from the input parameters.
            Entity entity = (Entity)context.InputParameters["Target"];

            // Verify that the target entity represents an annotation. If not, this plug-in was not registered correctly.
            if (entity.LogicalName != "annotation")
                return;

            tracingService.Trace("A Plugin is triggered!", "My Plugin");
        }

            .....

    }


}
```

The plugin is working as expected when I run it in debug mode and execute with no errors. When I attach a document to my entity the plugin does not execute at all and no errors are logged.

Any ideas how to diagnose this? or what is missing?

Answer (score 0):

1. Try to change it to sync plugin & verify if it trigger at all. You can throw `InvalidpluginExecutionException` in first line itself to verify
2. Good that you are using Tracing service (guess you have trimmed the code here?), Check the Plugin Trace logs for any exceptions by navigating to Settings - Plugin Trace log